# How to recursively delete Registry Key using DeleteSubkeyTree

Tags: c#

Code:

```
try 
{
     RegistryKey SQMRegKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("CurrentControlSet\\Control\\WMI\\Autologger", true);
     //SQMRegKey.DeleteSubKey("SQMLogger");
     SQMRegKey.DeleteSubKeyTree("SQMLogger");
     SQMRegKey.Close();
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{
     MessageBox.Show(this, ex.ToString());
}
```

always throws exception System.NullReferenceException:Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The registry path is not correct. Please use the below modified code:

```
        try
        {
            RegistryKey SQMRegKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("System\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\WMI\\Autologger", true);
            //SQMRegKey.DeleteSubKey("SQMLogger");

            SQMRegKey.DeleteSubKeyTree("SQMLogger");

            SQMRegKey.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Thanks that did it , you were correct I missed the system

Answer (score 0):

[OpenSubKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.opensubkey?view=netframework-4.7.2) may fail, in which case the return value is `null`. You use the reference, i.e. `SQMRegKey` without checking if it actually points to a valid object.

```
try 
{
     var SQMRegKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("CurrentControlSet\\Control\\WMI\\Autologger", true);
     if(SQMRegKey != null)
     {
        SQMRegKey.DeleteSubKeyTree("SQMLogger");
        SQMRegKey.Close();
     }
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{
     MessageBox.Show(this, ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I take note of the reference to the null value and will look to using != or GetValue method